# How to simulate keypress in an iFrame using javascript or query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, keypress

I am currently trying to write a script using javascript along side a bit of html and some css - but let's stick with Javascript as thats where, I think, my problem comes from...

In short what I want my program to do is these following points:

- I have an iFrame in the main window of my program.
- The iFrame is used to access a website (obviously duh :P)
- There is a button outside of the iFrame.
- That button will call a function when pressed by the user.
- HERE'S MY PROBLEM:
- I want that function to simulate the press of a keyboard key (in that case, a number key followed by the ENTER key twice.
- The thing is, I need to 'simulate' these keypress inside the iFrame, so they interact with the website that is access through the iFrame.

In short, I can't seem to find a way to interact with the website in iFrame from outside of it. I would prefer a solution using pure JS but I'm fully aware that there would probably be a much simpler solution using Jquery. So I'm open to either one of them.

I don't think that pieces of my code would help as there is basically nothing coded so far, besides the main function and the basic layout of the page. I'm ready to redo the whole architecture of what I've done so far if needed.

Thanks for you help. 
Yann

Comment: is the website in the iframe on your own domain/server, or is it a separate website? If its a different website, then short answer, no

Comment: Yes it's on a separate domain, it is not my website, I'm just accessing it through the iFrame. So there is no way to do that?

Comment: no way to do that. javascript will not let you access the contents of an iframe on a different domain. you can do it serverside with a tool like phantomJS